# Swap alternate bytes in a integer

Tags: c, byte, bit, swap

Problem: swap alternate bytes as below:

Input: uint8_t buf[4] = {0xab,0xcd,0xef,0xba};

Output: 0xcdababef

I have the below code for doing that but I am wondering if there is any better way to shorten the code.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define SWAP_16(buf) (((buf & 0xFF00) >> 8) | ((buf & 0x00FF) << 8))
int main()
{
    unsigned int value;
    int i, j=0;
    uint8_t buf[4] = {0,4,0,0};
    unsigned int mask = 0xFFFF;
    unsigned int tmp_value;
    unsigned int size = 4;

    for (i = size - 1 ;i >= 0; i--) {
        tmp_value |= (buf[j] << 8*i);
        j++;
    }

    value = SWAP_16((tmp_value & (mask << 16)) >> 16) << 16 |
        SWAP_16(tmp_value & mask);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use an `int` ? Just swap the bytes in the array....

Comment: `#define SWAPPED(b) { b[1], b[0], b[3], b[2] }` ... `uint8_t bswap[4] = SWAPPED(buf);` .. ?

Comment: did you mean `0xcdabbaef` as intended output  ? If not then it's unclear what your stipulation is

Comment: (for 32-bit `unsigned int`): `value = ((value & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((value & 0x00ff00ff) << 8);`

Comment: @M.M: it is the expected output as clearly explained. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @Dmitri: If you write that as a answer then i will mark that as the correct answer. I think this is exactly what was escaping my mind.

Comment: @M.M: can you explain what you are doing in your code below? I think Dmitri answer is pretty simple and easy to read.

Comment: @user3053970 your input contains a byte `ba` but your output does not contain any byte `ba`. But your text says you want bytes swapped, so that does not make sense.

Comment: @user3053970 select the answer you like best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `unsigned int` is 32-bits, you can simply use:

```
value = ((value & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((value & 0x00ff00ff) << 8);
```

to swap the bytes in each pair of bytes in `value`.  It's similar to your `SWAP_16()` macro except that it does both halves of the value at once.

Comment: This does not work for the stipulated input format of `uint8_t buf[4] = {0xab,0xcd,0xef,0xba};`

Comment: @M.M It does the byte swapping, it just doesn't put the bytes of the array into the `unsigned int` first... his code already did that before swapping the bytes anyway (though there are of course other ways).

Comment: @user3053970 Or use `memcpy()` which will copy in the right order (for before the swap) on big endian machines... for little endian like x86 you can still use `memcpy()` if you swap the halves instead of the bytes within them, eg. `value = ((value & 0xffff0000) >> 16) | ((value & 0x0000ffff) << 16);`.  Or you can use a union, but that'll have similar endianness issues.  Or shift each array element to its final position as you copy, eg. `value = (buf[0] << 16) | (buf[1] << 24) | buf[2] | (buf[3] << 8);`, instead of copying then swapping... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a union

```
#include <stdint.h>


#define SWAP_VAR(T, v1, v2) do { \
  T v = (v1); \
  (v1) = (v2); \
  (v2) = v; \
} while (0);

union U32
{
  uint32_t u;
  unsigned char a[4];
};

uint32_t swap32(uint32_t u)
{
  union U32 u32 = {u};

  SWAP_VAR(unsigned char, u32.a[0], u32.a[1]);
  SWAP_VAR(unsigned char, u32.a[2], u32.a[3]);

  return u32.u;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t swap32(uint32_t u);


int main(void)
{
  uint32_t u = 0x12345678;
  u = swap32(u);
}
```

Comment: did you run this program?

Comment: `a[2] = c;` should be `a[3] = c;`

Comment: Yes, yes, fixed this sloppiness ... sorry! @M.M

Comment: @user3053970: Fair enough, but the concept was clear, wasn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t buf[4] = {0xab,0xcd,0xef,0xba};

    unsigned int out = buf[1] * 0x1000000u + buf[0] * 0x10000u + buf[3] * 0x100u + buf[2];
    printf("%x\n", out);
}
```

Comment: Do you understand the place value system , e.g. in decimal 123 means 100 + 20 + 3.  it is the same in hex  , 0x123 means 0x100 + 0x20 + 0x3.  In this case we work two digits at a time: 0x12345678 means 0x12000000 + 0x340000 + 0x5600 + 0x78.

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear from your question if it's not an option, but you could merely just swap the bytes in the array if you know the size won't change:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define SWAPPED(b) { b[1], b[0], b[3], b[2] }
#define PRINT(b) printf("0x0%x\n", *((uint32_t*)b));

int main()
{
    uint8_t buf[4] = {8,4,6,1};
    uint8_t swapped[4] = SWAPPED(buf);
    PRINT(buf);
    PRINT(swapped);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for this on my machine is:

```
0x01060408
0x06010804
```

This is because of endian-ness and printing an array casted to an integer type, but the bytes are swapped as you ask in your question.

Hope that helps.

Comment: nice sneaky logic. Where did you get this idea from :)?

Comment: @user3053970, I've been doing C for a while :)

Comment: Note that this has an aliasing problem

Comment: @user3053970, what do you mean it doesn't give the output? That's the expected output given what your printing.

Comment: @txtechhelp: look carefully at the output

Comment: @user3053970, yup, `6010804` is what I would expect on a system with `int`'s as 32 bit's and with strict aliasing and other flags set .. swapping bytes and printing them are 2 separate things .. When I print the code you posted I get `0x040001` and `0x04000100` ..

Comment: @4386427: Isn't the printing more an alignment issue?

Comment: @txtechhelp: http://ideone.com/rPisuk weird that on your system the output differs.

Comment: @user3053970, it's not weird when you use a different compiler: [https://ideone.com/hNjxv7](https://ideone.com/hNjxv7) .. :)

Comment: `*((uint32_t*)b` causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule

Comment: @M.M, yes .. but swapping bytes doesn't break the rules, the casting was for output only

Comment: @alk - Accessing the `uint8_t` array using a `uint32_t` pointer violates the strict aliasing rule. That's UB by itself. But I think that your are right about alignment may be a problem as well for some systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int n = ((unsigned int)buf[0] << 16) |
                 ((unsigned int)buf[1] << 24) |
                 ((unsigned int)buf[2] <<  0) |
                 ((unsigned int)buf[3] <<  8);
```